# What is a module's binary in python

Tags: python, django, binary

I've seen the word "binary" a couple times when dealing with python, and specifically when dealing with django  manage.py, but do not know what it means.  An example of "binary" in context is, "the celery binary is located in the path this/path/here".  In the previous sentence celery is a python module.  Can someone please explain to me what "binary" means and how I can find it's path.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When used that way, "binary" is a synonym for "main executable", or whatever can be run to actually get the thing to start.

So the location will be wherever you installed it. If you can access it by typing its name, and you run a *nix box, you can get the location by typing `which <name>`.

```
$ which celery
/home/spectras/Projects/<...>/env/bin/celery
```

Comment: Thanks.  So the location would be where I installed the module?  For example, something like C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\celery?

Comment: I'm not running windows now so I cannot check, but I guess you should have something like   `C:\Python34\bin\celery.exe` or `C:\Python34\scripts\celery.exe`. Or with `.py`, I don't really know the naming scheme on windows. Find it with file explorer if it's not there.